# getting java exception: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol

Tags: java, url, io

I am currently calling the following line of code:

```
java.net.URL connection_url = new java.net.URL("http://<ip address>:<port>/path");
```

and I get the exception above when it executes.  Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: I'm not getting that same exception with the exact same code.

Comment: What version of Java is causing the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        java.net.URL connection_url = new java.net.URL("http://:/path");
        System.out.println("Instantiated new URL: " + connection_url);
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

> Instantiated new URL: http://:/path

Sure you have the right line of code?

Answer (score 3):

As a side note, you should be using [URI](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) because Java URL class is screwed up. (The equals method I believe)

Comment: Not sure why the parent got modded down, but it might be a good idea to use URI in place of URL depending on what you're doing. See: http://www.symphonious.net/2007/03/29/javaneturl-or-javaneturi/

Comment: You probably *don't* want to use java.net.URI if you're working with URLs as found in the wild (often invalid URIs).

Answer (score 2):

That url string looks like it's invalid. Sure it's not supposed to be 'http://path'? Or are the server & port blank?

Comment: Thanks! that worked for me. Had missed adding the protocol before the IP address. I guess Chrome has spoiled me :)

Answer (score 1):

I have also had the same exception, but in my case the URL which I was trying to execute had a space appended. After removing the space it worked fine for me. Check that the URL does not have any trailing spaces in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and it got resolved by the below :

The jar files (JFree) which I added few days back got corrupted automatically and was causing this error. I downloaded the same files again from net and it worked fine for me.